# Upload Image и Парсинг XML документа

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер

Есть функция отправки изображения на сервер с получением ответа в виде XML

Проблема состоит в том что изображение отправляется на сервер и  ответ приходит(текст), но если вставляю парсинг, то функция перестает работать!
Вот вид документа, который приходит как ответ от сервера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imagehost>
<file>
    <url>URL изображения</url>
    <delurl>URL страницы удаления изображения</delurl>
    <width>ширина изображения (число целое, px)</width>
    <height>высота изображения (число целое, px)</height>
    <size>размер файла (строковое представления размера)</size>
    <preview_url>URL эскиза</preview_url>
    <pwidth>ширина эскиза (число целое, px)</pwidth>
    <pheight>высота эскиза (число целое, px)</pheight>
    <psize>размер файла эскиза (строковое представления размера)</psize>
</file>
</imagehost>
```

---

Сама функция:

```
public void executeMultipartPost() throws Exception {

  try {


 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

 Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);

byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(

"http://forpics.ru/upload");

String fileName = String.format("File_%d.png",new Date().getTime());
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);

// File file= new File("/mnt/sdcard/forest.png");

// FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(

HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

reqEntity.addPart("uploadfile", bab);

postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
int timeoutConnection = 60000;
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 60000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

String sResponse;

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {

s = s.append(sResponse);
String site = s.toString();
//text.setText(site);
//Парсинг
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(site));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
//-----------

//Результат не зависит от того, где находятся эти узлы.

NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("url");

int count = list.getLength();

for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)

{

    Node n= list.item(i);

    //Собственно здесь и обрабатываем все элементы.



    n.getNodeValue();//Получение значения элемента. Внизу опишу пояснения небольшие.

    n.getFirstChild();//Получение первого ребенка.


    text.setText(n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    //и т.д.

}   
//конец парсинга

}

System.out.println("Response: " + s);

} catch (Exception e) {

// handle exception here
    e.printStackTrace();
    text.setText("Ошибка!");
    // Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас коллега проблема: сначала читаете документ в потоке, затем пытаетесь воспользоваться для парсинга методом DOM, что не есть айс, ибо DOM требует весь документ целиком, а SAX спокойно работает с потоком.

Я бы напустил сразу на `reader` SAX парсер и голову бы не грел.